# XSL word citation change

Tags: xslt, ms-word, bibliography

I have found a *.xsl citation template for Word 2010. It is almost what I need I just need a few changes done.

First it shows in the output e.g. [Str17] but it should show [STR-17]
Further it shows the bibliography not in a table with a tab in between the TAG and the entry.

e.g.

[looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFpxZ.png)

but i need

[I need that format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekiu8.png)

I just can't adjust the xsl to my needs. I have been trying for a while now and trying to find any other xsl file but no luck. This kind to citation is pretty common in engineering so I am sure I am not the only one looking for a solution.

I think for the first part of my question regarding the style of the Tag the relevant code is:

```
 <xsl:if test="msxsl:node-set($ListPopulatedWithMain)/b:Citation/b:FirstAuthor">
                        <!-- hier wird die Klammer [ angezeigt -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_ISO690_GeneralOpen"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="msxsl:node-set($ListPopulatedWithMain)/b:Citation/b:PagePrefix">

                    <xsl:value-of select="/b:Citation/b:PagePrefix"/>

                    </xsl:if>

                    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="$displayAuthor" /> nicht den Author anzeigen sondern den Tag-->
                    <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($ListPopulatedWithMain)/b:Citation/b:Source/b:Tag" />

                    <xsl:if test="string-length($displayTitle) > 0">
                        <xsl:if test="string-length($displayAuthor) > 0">
                            <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>


                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$displayTitle"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="string-length($year) > 0">
                        <xsl:if test="string-length($displayTitle) > 0">
                            <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
                        </xsl:if>   
                        <!-- <xsl:value-of select="$year"/> nicht das Jahr anzeigen lassen -->
                    </xsl:if>


                    <xsl:if test="string-length($author0) = 0 and string-length($title0) = 0 and string-length($year0) = 0">
                        <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($ListPopulatedWithMain)/b:Citation/b:Source/b:Tag"/>
                    </xsl:if>


                    <xsl:if test="string-length($volume) > 0 or string-length($pages) > 0">
                        <xsl:if test="string-length($displayAuthor) > 0 or string-length($displayTitle) > 0 or string-length($year) > 0">
                            <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_Space"/>
                        </xsl:if>           

                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="string-length($volume) > 0 and string-length($pages) > 0">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$volume"/>
                                <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_Enum"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$pages"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="string-length($volVolume) > 0">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$volVolume"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="string-length($ppPages) > 0">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$ppPages"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="/b:Citation/b:PageSuffix">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/b:Citation/b:PageSuffix"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="/b:Citation/b:LastAuthor">
                        <!-- hier wird die Klammer ] angezeigt -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_ISO690_GeneralClose"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="not(/b:Citation/b:LastAuthor)">
                        <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_GroupSeparator"/>
                    </xsl:if>
```

I have tried to add - in this part but it just shows the hyphen at the beginning or at the end. Changing the letters into uppercase is still magic for me. could not find the relevant section.

For the 2nd part I will upload the file since it is pretty long and i don't want to post the entire code. Can't do it from work since every possibility for an upload is blocked by my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I would recommend you to use templates e.g:

```
<xsl:template name="Citation">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="FirstAuthor">
    <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_ISO690_GeneralOpen"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="PagePrefix">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
</xsl:template>
...
```

This is not necessary, but better code style.
Your code is unreadable for me so I will answer your question like that:
 - For transforming the text to upper-case use

```
<xsl:value-of select="upper-case(//some-xpath)"/>
```

- To insert tables use code like this:

  Text


  Text

If you expect a better answer please post some readable code

Comment: I understand. sorry for that. This is a code I actaully found and i wanted to adjust it. Haven't realised that it is that unreadable.

Comment: For some odd reason it is not showing the table code:
       <fo:table>
        <fo:table-body>
         <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell width="30%"><fo:block>Text</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
          <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Text</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
         </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
       </fo:table> 
Just post it again after you refactored it a bit :)